# Downloaded free template but got: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I get error `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` in `scripts.js` when I download and run this [template](http://www.bootstrapzero.com/theme/landing-zero/) locally. I haven't changed anything in the template.

I checked to make sure that JQuery is the first script loaded, and the JQuery scripts seem to be working... but the `scripts.js` file doesn't seem to load. You can see it at the bottom of the index file:

```
</div>
<!--scripts loaded here from cdn for performance -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Why is this error happening?

Comment: Are you just opening your file using the filebrowser? `//` protocols do not work from inside the `file://` protocol. How locally is this? My guess is you are not running it on a `localhost`. If you want these to work inside this protocol, test it out by adding `http:` in front of the `//` urls and see if your problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `//` are used to help the browser select a protocol for you depending on the protocol you are using. If you are using `https`, then it will try to use the `https` protocol - this allows Google the freedom to move you between secured and unsecured protocols. However, `file://` could be considered a private protocol, something that the browser should not really access. On top of that, I highly doubt that you have a matching location on your computer anyhow. Do you have a folder located here:

```
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
```

I doubt it. So the fetching of jQuery fails because the matching protocol is `file` and not `http`, which is not allowed! You can easily use one of two fixes for this.

The first is adding `http:` or `https:` (although that might not work as `file` is not considered secure) before the `//`.

The second, which is the one I recommend, is to use a `localhost`. You can look into MAMP for easy GUI, or Vagrant for incredible flexibility, but many systems allow you to host you site on an address that is 'on the web' and considered 'home' at the same time. When you run your page on such a webserver, you will get all the benefits of being on a webserver without ever actually being on an actual webserver, so have a look into those as they will make developing for the web much easier. From then on, your site is probably hosted on something similar to this: `http://localhost:8888` - but as you can see, the protocols now line up and everything starts working.

Comment: Thanks! I learned something very important about protocols today :)

Comment: @phil no worries - i can kind of guess who it was after i downvoted him ;) at least my reason wasn't petty revenge (if he hadnt done it word for word i wouldn't have downvoted)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is of protocol. `//` protocols do not work from inside the `file://` protocol.  My guess is you are not running it on a localhost. If you want these to work inside this protocol, test it out by adding `http:` in front of the `//` urls and see if your problem goes

**Update Script Tag**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: @somethinghere haha i almost accepted the solution till i saw your comment. you were right, and i would never have found the solution without your help so post your solution and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Phil should I simply copy and paste his solution? ;) I'm on it!

Comment: @Phil I decided to go a bit further and try to explain it a bit more and give you a potentially time-saving solution for the future! Good luck :)

Comment: @Bhavin Solanki, I upvoted your answer because you showed me exactly where to add the `https:` to the code. I appreciate the effort but I can't accept it given the solution was given 10 minutes earlier. All I can do is make your solution 0 instead of -2.